# How to remove file paths from github files in my repository?

Tags: git, github

I'm new to github.  I'm trying to host my project on github pages but my file was added as Desktop/app instead of directly pushing the actual project files(index.html, etc.) to the repository.  It looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mi2ha.jpg

I don't want the files to be in a desktop/app folder.  Thanks.

Comment: your repo should start at app - you might want to recreate.

Comment: Deleting the repo fixed the issue.  Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have cloned your project at `Desktop/app`. If you don't want this repo, you can to delete from your GitHub account. Check this Link [Deleting Git Repo](https://help.github.com/articles/deleting-a-repository/)

Try to make new one -

Go to the folder where you want have stored your project, and clone the new repository: 
[Create GitHub Repo](https://help.github.com/articles/create-a-repo/)

```
$git clone https://github.com/user_name/repository_name.git
$git add --all
$git commit -m "Your commit msg"
$git push -u origin master
```

Comment: Deleting the repo fixed the issue but it was strange because it was not a cloned project to begin with. I made the repo from scratch.  Very weird.  Thanks for the help though!

Comment: What is the error for cloning ? 
If it is helpful, please accept the answer or upvote.